# How can I change the background-color and color of matBadge?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to change both the background and text color of a Material badge instead of using the standard material color, how do I do this?

```
<mat-icon matBadge="{{this.userService.numberOfCartItems}}" 
     matBadgePosition="above after" matBadgeColor="accent">
     shopping_cart
</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can change the background and color properties for the class mat-badge-content:

```
.mat-badge-content {
    background: red;
    color: blue;
}
```